# Auto Resize ALL dialogs using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog

I found some code in another post on Stackoverflow for auto-sizing jQuery dialogs in IE and ensuring they don't simply size to the width of the screen...it works great, even on IE7!

```
$("#item-popup").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable: false,
    autoResize: true,
    width: 'auto',
    modal: true
}).bind("dialogopen", function(event, ui) {
    // only run on IE
    if ($.browser.msie) {
        // fix for width:auto in IE  
        var contentWidth = $(this).width();
        $(this).parent().find('.ui-dialog-titlebar').each(function() {
            $(this).width(contentWidth);
        });
    }
}).bind("dialogclose", function(event, ui) {
    // only run on IE
    if ($.browser.msie) {
        //fix for width:auto in IE 
        $(this).parent().css("width", "auto");
    }
});
```

What I want to do now is apply this same code to all of the other dialogs on my page without having to repeat it over and over.  I've tried a bunch of variations of the logic but I just can't seem to get it right.  I can get the dialogopen code to fire, but it doesn't resize the dialog at all like it does when I bind it directly to the dialog.

```
$('.ui-dialog').bind("dialogopen", function(event, ui) {
    // only run on IE
    if ($.browser.msie) {
        // fix for width:auto in IE  
        var contentWidth = $(this).width();
        $(this).parent().find('.ui-dialog-titlebar').each(function() {
            $(this).width(contentWidth); // <-- Does not resize the dialog
        });
    }
}).bind("dialogclose", function(event, ui) {
    // only run on IE
    if ($.browser.msie) {
        //fix for width:auto in IE 
        $(this).parent().css("width", "auto");
    }
});
```

After much troubleshooting I've found that the problem is in the line of code that gets the contentWidth.  When bound directly to the dialog it returns only the width of dialog (i.e. 435), but when I have it in this generic handler it returns the window width (i.e. 1150).

Am I referencing the dialog incorrectly in the generic ui-dialog handler?

```
var contentWidth = $(this).width();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are right your reference was incorrect.  In order to bind to the same dialog element you should be referencing `$(".ui-dialog-content").bind("dialogopen", ...`

Comment: Works great, thanks! With one additional line of code I have it centering now too: $('#' + event.target.id).dialog("option", "position", "center");